# Mysql duplicate entry not readable in java application logs

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, exception, duplicates

I'm getting this error using my application :

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '\xC3\x91\xAFW\xF8\xAE+A\xE7\xE8\x1D\x0B\xA6^\xCA6\xD9\xB9_\xA2l\' for key 'IDX_CTRL_CARD_LISTS_UK'
```

But the thing is that I would liket to decode the character chain 
`\xC3\x91\xAFW\xF8\xAE+A\xE7\xE8\x1D\x0B\xA6^\xCA6\xD9\xB9_\xA2l\`
in order to be able to find out the duplicate entry in my database.
The main issue here I guess is that my key is composed of multiple column checks so this chain may be a combination of all the values

I've checked few encodings and the utf-8 literal encoding seemed to be the closest but I am not sure about this.

Does anyone know how to convert this entry into something readable.

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: https://unicodelookup.com/

Comment: I don't see how this website helps me? when i type my character chain, it doesn't give much information